# NSScanner only working with non-initialized variables. Why?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsscanner

The following code works, but produces warnings about non-initialized variables.

The code parses a string representing a molecule, such as @"2C12;5H1;1O16".  It checks that it is correctly formatted and that all the components are valid isotopes.  As listed, it works perfectly, but produces warnings from the compiler.

```
//listOfNames is a global variable, an NSArray containing strings of all isotope names i.e. @"Na23"

-(bool)canGrokSpeciesName:(NSString*)theSpeciesName{
 //Test that the species name makes sense
 //Names should be of the form of repeated @"nnSSaa" with nn being the multiplier, SS being the element name, aa being the atomic mass number

bool couldGrok = [theSpeciesName isNotEqualTo:@""];
if(couldGrok){

    NSArray* listOfAtomsWithMultiplier = [theSpeciesName componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];

    for (int i=0; i<[listOfAtomsWithMultiplier count]; i++) NSLog(@"%@", [listOfAtomsWithMultiplier objectAtIndex:i]);

    NSInteger multiplet[ [listOfAtomsWithMultiplier count] ];
    bool ok[ [listOfAtomsWithMultiplier count] ];

    bool noFail = true;
    for (int i=0; i<[listOfAtomsWithMultiplier count]; i++) {
        NSScanner* theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:[listOfAtomsWithMultiplier objectAtIndex:i]];
        NSString* multipletString;

        if(![theScanner isAtEnd]) [theScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] intoString:&multipletString];
        multiplet[i] = [multipletString integerValue];

        NSString* atomString;
        if(![theScanner isAtEnd]) [theScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] intoString:&atomString];

        NSInteger A;
        if(![theScanner isAtEnd]) [theScanner scanInteger:&A];

        NSLog(@"%@%i with multiplet of %i", atomString, (int)A, (int)multiplet[i]);
        bool hasBeenFound = false;
        for(int j=0; j<[listOfNames count]; j++){
            if(noFail) hasBeenFound = hasBeenFound || [[listOfNames objectAtIndex:j] isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i", atomString, (int)A]];
        }
        couldGrok = couldGrok && noFail && hasBeenFound;
    }
}

return couldGrok;
```

}

However, if I initialize with

```
NSString* multipletString = @"";
NSString* atomString = @"";
NSInteger A = -1;
```

then the NSScanner returns them with their originally initialized values.  Am I missing something basic?

I prefer not to ignore warnings from the compiler, but following the compiler suggestions breaks the code.  So, I suppose this is more a request for basic information than a request for how to fix my code.  Thanks!

Comment: Fix the example code: `listOfNames` is undeclared. Also as an ObjC convention variable name start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Can you please explain what output you wanted exactly??

Comment: listOfNames is an NSArray containing all the allowable isotope names, such as @"Na23", etc.

Comment: The goal is to take a molecule such as @"2H1;1O16" and verify that the component isotopes are valid.  The code works as posted, but I get compilation warning advising me to initialize the three variables mentioned.  Doing so results in the code no longer working...

Comment: Have you stepped through the code to see what happens in both case (initialized and uninitialized)? Also, why initialize them to strings instead of, for example, `NSString* multipletString = nil;` and `NSInteger A = 0;`?

Comment: You should be using `BOOL` instead of `bool`. What are the compiler warnings? If you are compiling this with ARC, it won't be necessary to initialize the pointers to `nil`, but it is a good habit to follow. Since `count` returns `NSUInteger`, you should use that type for `i` instead of `int`. Since the value of `noFail` never changes,  it's useless.

Comment: @ShaggyFrog, thank you. noFail is a left-over.  I had 

if(![theScanner isAtEnd]) noFail = [theScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] intoString:&multipletString];

but that result in incorrect output.  I will try initializing to nil and using BOOL.  What is the precise difference between bool and BOOL?

Comment: @ShaggyFrog: I still don't understand my initial trouble, but your suggestion certainly fixed it.  Thank you very much!

Can you post that as an answer so I can mark it as solved and clear this?